# Moq Mocking with Identity 2.0 Database

Tags: unit-testing, moq, entity-framework-6.1, asp.net-identity-2

I successfully set up an Integration Test using mocking with Moq against my BusAct controller in an MVC 5, Entity Framework 6 app based on a Simple membership database.  But now I have migrated the database to Identity 2.0 and replaced the UserProfile with ApplicationUser.

IdentityDbContext: (Modified from Simple membership DbContext)

```
  public class MyDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> // DbContext  
  {
    public MyDb () : base("MyApplication") { }

    // public virtual DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BusAcnt> BusAcnts { get; set; } // marking as virtual allows mocking override
    public virtual DbSet<...>
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
  }
```

MockDbSetup:

```
  public class MockDbSetup
  {
    public static Mock<MyDb> MockMyDb()
    {
      var dataBa = new List<BusAcnt>  {
        new BusAcnt {Id = 0, CmpnyName = "Company 1", NmOfc = 1, Status = "Active"},
        new BusAcnt {Id = 1, CmpnyName = "Company 2", NmOfc = 1, Status = "Active"},
        new BusAcnt {Id = 2, CmpnyName = "Company 3", NmOfc = 1, Status = "Active"},
        new BusAcnt {Id = 3, CmpnyName = "Company 4", NmOfc = 1, Status = "Active"},
        new BusAcnt {Id = 4, CmpnyName = "Company 5", NmOfc = 1, Status = "Active"},
        new BusAcnt {Id = 5, CmpnyName = "Company 6", NmOfc = 1, Status = "Active"}
      }.AsQueryable();
      var mockSetBa = new Mock<DbSet<BusAcnt>>();
      mockSetBa.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(dataBa.Provider);
      mockSetBa.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(dataBa.Expression);
      mockSetBa.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(dataBa.ElementType);
      mockSetBa.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dataBa.GetEnumerator());
      var MyDb = new Mock<MyDb>();
      mockMyDb.Setup(c => c.BusAcnts).Returns(mockSetBa.Object);
      return mockMyDb;
    }
  }
```

Integration Test:

```
[Fact]
public void GetAllBusAcnt()
{
  var mockMyDb = MockDBSetup.MockMyDb();
  var controller = new BusAcntController(mockMyDb.Object);
  var controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
  controllerContextMock.Setup(
      x => x.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals("admin")))
      ).Returns(true);
  controller.ControllerContext = controllerContextMock.Object;

  var viewResult = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
  var model = viewResult.Model as PagedBusIdxModel;

  Assert.NotNull(model);
  Assert.Equal(6, model.BusAcnts.ToList().Count());
  Assert.Equal("Company 2", model.BusAcnts.ToList()[1].CmpnyName);
}
```

When I run the test now I get these errors:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationExceptionOne or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Castle.Proxies.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Castle.Proxies.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps()
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext db)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString, Boolean throwIfV1Schema)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at MyApplication.Models.MyDb..ctor() in MyDb.cs: line 9
   at Castle.Proxies.MyDbProxy..ctor(IInterceptor[])
```

I believe I need to modify the MockDbSetup but have not been able to find any information on how to do that.

I tried adding

```
  var dataUsr = new List<ApplicationUser>
  {
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "Test", PasswordHash = "a123cdefg"} }.AsQueryable();
  var mockSetUsr = new Mock<DbSet<ApplicationUser>>();
  mockSetUsr.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(dataUsr.Provider);
  mockSetUsr.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(dataUsr.Expression);
  mockSetUsr.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(dataUsr.ElementType);
  mockSetUsr.As<IQueryable<BusAcnt>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dataUsr.GetEnumerator());
```

But I get a "Can't resolve" error on `GetEnumerator`

And neither

```
  mockMyDb.Setup(c => c.AspNetUsers).Returns(mockSetUsr.Object);
```

or

```
  mockMyDb.Setup(c => c.ApplicationUser).Returns(mockSetUsr.Object);
```

works because it cannot resolve either `AspNetUsers` or `ApplicationUser`.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this, links to documentation on mocking an Identity 2.0 database would be especially helpful?

Comment: Does the answer to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907581/testing-framework-says-entity-has-no-key-defined-for-built-in-entity

Comment: I believe these are Unit, not Integration tests, as you're not hitting the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to Jamie and in turn Andreas' answer at [Testing framework says entity has no key defined for built in entity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907581/testing-framework-says-entity-has-no-key-defined-for-built-in-entity)

In the `MockMyDb()` method in `MockDbSetup` add `{ CallBase = true };` to `var MyDb = new Mock<MyDb>();` resulting in

```
var MyDb = new Mock<MyDb>() { CallBase = true };
```

Answer (score 2):

While there may be a way to get EF to bypass it's internal behavior for the purpose of mocking, by far the easiest method is to use IDbSet instead of DbSet, and extract an interface off of your MyDb instance.

```
public interface IMyDb   
{
    IDbSet<BusAcnt> BusAcnts { get; set; } // marking as virtual allows mocking override
    IDbSet<...>

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

What you're currently doing is a partial mock which I've always found to be problematic. I just avoid it.