# Unit testing with MOQ & EFCore using .Find with composite primary key

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to moq the EF Core 'Find' functionality using a composite primary key. A work colleague has pointed in one direction which does appear to work but I am wondering if there is a better solution?

This is what I have so far.

I have a factory class for creating a mock DB set. I am creating the DB set from a list objects that have this structure;

```
public int FK { get; set; }
public string SourceId { get; }
public string EntityName { get; set; }
public int? EntityKey { get; set; }
public string IdLong { get; set; }
```

The primary key consists FK, EntityName & SourceId.

This is how I am currently creating my DBSet

```
  var assocMock = EFCoreFactory.CreateMockDBSet(new List<AData> { obj1, obj2});


  // Map the associated data for the EF .Find to work
  assocMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.Is<object[]>(mm =>
     mm[0] as int? == obj1.FK &&
     mm[1].ToString() == obj1.EntityName &&
     mm[2].ToString() == obj1.SourceId
    ))).Returns(obj1);

  assocMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.Is<object[]>(mm =>
     mm[0] as int? == obj2.FK &&
     mm[1].ToString() == obj2.EntityName &&
     mm[2].ToString() == obj2.SourceId
    ))).Returns(obj2);

  EFCoreFactory.CreateMockSet<AData>(context, assocMock.Object);
```

Can anybody suggest any better or more generic way to do this?

**UPDATE** based on the link provided by Shafiq below this is my latest attempt which I think is a bit more generic and wont require me to map each individual object. Can anybody see any flaw in this approach?

```
  assocMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
           .Returns<object[]>(ad => assocDataList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FK == (int)ad[0] &&
                                                                      d.EntityName == ad[1].ToString() &&
                                                                      d.SourceId == ad[2].ToString()))
```

Comment: Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956071/1718312

Comment: You might also want to consider adding the key via the Fluent API, as shown at the end of the Configuring a Primary Key section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key

Comment: Does the in memory provider not work?

Comment: The suggestions so far though helpful unfortunately do not quite achieve my intended goal, thanks though. The link provided by Shafiq is helpful and I have already specified the composite key for the entity but omitted in my example for brevity. Unfortunately rgvlee the in memory provider cannot be used in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the answer that I have gone with and works for me quite well, many thanks all.

```
assocMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
           .Returns<object[]>(ad => assocDataList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FK == (int)ad[0] &&
                                                                      d.EntityName == ad[1].ToString() &&
                                                                      d.SourceId == ad[2].ToString()))
```