# DbContext mock with MOQ for SqlQuery() test - There is already an object named 'public' in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

Let's say I have method like that:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>> GetFor(int idUser)
{
    // query used in below _dbContext.SqlQuery() function contains joins to 3 tables: document, tamplate and user
    var result = await _dbContext.SqlQuery("SELECT ...").ToListAsync();
    // do something operations on result
    return result;
}
```

Now I need write some unit tests for it:

```
[Test]
public async Task GetFor_ForUserWhichHasTemplates_ReturnsNonEmptyCollectionOfSomeViewModel()
{
    // arrange
    // create dummy data for tables used in joins
    var documentTableMock = Builder<Document>.CreateListOfSize(15)
                                             .All().With(x => x.id_user = 1)
                                             .TheFirst(5).With(x => x.id_template = 1)
                                             .TheNext(6).With(x => x.id_template = 2)
                                             .TheLast(4).With(x => x.id_template = 3)
                                             .TheLast(1).With(x => x.id_user = 2)
                                             .Build();
     var templateTableMock = Builder<Template>.CreateListOfSize(3).Build();
     var userTableMock = Builder<User>.CreateListOfSize(1).Build();

     var dbMock = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>() { CallBase = true };
     
     // mock table for SqlQuery() function
     var documentTable = new Mock<DbSet<Document>>();
     documentTable.Setup(m => m.SqlQuery(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
                  .Returns<string, object[]>((sql, param) =>
                   {
                        var sqlQueryMock = new Mock<DbSqlQuery<Document>>();
                        sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.AsNoTracking())
                                    .Returns(sqlQueryMock.Object);
                        sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
                                    .Returns(documentTableMock.GetEnumerator());
                        return sqlQueryMock.Object;
                    });

        var templateTable = new Mock<DbSet<Template>>();
        templateTable.Setup(m => m.SqlQuery(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
                     .Returns<string, object[]>((sql, param) =>
                     {
                         var sqlQueryMock = new Mock<DbSqlQuery<Template>>();
                         sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.AsNoTracking())
                             .Returns(sqlQueryMock.Object);
                         sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
                             .Returns(templateTableMock.GetEnumerator());
                         return sqlQueryMock.Object;
                     });

        var userTable = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();
        userTable.Setup(m => m.SqlQuery(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
                 .Returns<string, object[]>((sql, param) =>
                 {
                     var sqlQueryMock = new Mock<DbSqlQuery<User>>();
                     sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.AsNoTracking())
                         .Returns(sqlQueryMock.Object);
                     sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
                         .Returns(groupUserTableMock.GetEnumerator());
                     return sqlQueryMock.Object;
                 });


        dbMock.Setup(m => m.Set<Document>()).Returns(documentTable.Object);
        dbMock.Setup(m => m.Set<Template>()).Returns(templateTable.Object);
        dbMock.Setup(m => m.Set<User>()).Returns(userTable.Object);

        var templateService = new TemplateService(dbMock.Object);

        // act
        var result = await templateService.GetFor(1);

        // asserts
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(14, result.Count());
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(SomeViewModel), result.ElementAt(0));
}
```

Test didn't passed, I got an exception:

> There is already an object named 'public' in the database.

> CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.

It's true that I have an object named `public` in my database (it's schema name) but I don't understand why I got this exception - I thought I don't create new datbase instance, just fill dbContext mock with dummy data.

I also would like to add that other tests methods, which covered functions with linq expressions (`dbContext.Document.Where(x => x.id_document == ...)`) works great and tests completed successfully. Only test methods covered functions with `dbContext.SqlQuery()` failed.

How to force to mock dbContext with dummy data for testing functions with `SqlQuery()` inside?

@EDIT

My dbContext looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public virtual DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Document> Document{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> User{ get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        string connectionString = "my_connection_string";
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

`DefaultConnection` in web.config is empty:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How do you want to Mock non-abstract class? When we mock something - Mock framework creates dynamic proxy for Interface we are mocking and overrides its behaviour, and AFAIU - it is not your case

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk I've created dbContext mock in same way like in above post and tests working if in tested functions query was created with LINQ expressions.

Comment: dbMock.Setup(m => m.Set<Document>()).Returns(documentTable.Object);
        dbMock.Setup(m => m.Set<Template>()).Returns(templateTable.Object);
        dbMock.Setup(m => m.Set<User>()).Returns(userTable.Object); are all of those marked as virtual?

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk yes, Set<T>() function is virtual.

Comment: With callbase = true, whats in the dbcontext parameterless constructor? As it'll be executing it. Sounds like it's trying to create db objects.

Comment: @rgvlee I've updated my question with source code of my dbContext.

Comment: Is that your connection string, or have you subbed it out for this question? If you have a real connection string in there, callbase = true will mean anything not mocked executes as it normally would.

Comment: @rgvlee I have a real connection string there, I've just replaced it with random text for this question. I was trying with clean constructor (I've removed code responsible for inserting connection string) but nothing changed - still obtained error `There is already an object named 'public' in the database.`

Comment: Your `DefaultConnection` won't be loading from config, unless there is something unorthodox going on in your test fixture. If you've mocked everything required to run the `SqlQuery`, remove `CallBase = true` from the db context mock creation. You only need this if you want to create a partial mock. The only reason I can thing you'd get that error is if your mock is actually connecting to a db. Could be missing something but that's what it feels like

Comment: @rgvlee I used `Callbase = True` according to answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907581/testing-framework-says-entity-has-no-key-defined-for-built-in-entity 
As far I now there is no another solution for `EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined` exception.